# Codeigniter - Save input value in mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an input in my code that update a value in MySQL, but is not working, if i set the value manually in PHPMyAdmin, the value display in HTML, but when i try update, return to 0.

I have the same code to do a similar function, and have copied, and it still isn't working.

Controller:

```
function ordemmobile(){
    $ordemmobile = $this->input->post('ordemmobile');
    $id    = $this->input->post('id');

    if($id > 0){
        $data['ordemmobile'] = $ordemmobile;
        $data['id']    = $id;

        if( $this->categorias_model->alterar($data)){
            $ret = "success";
            $msg = "Ordem alterada com sucesso!";
        }else{
            $ret = "danger";
            $msg = "Erro ao alterar a ordem :(";
        }
    }else{
        $ret = "danger";
        $msg = "Erro ao alterar a ordem :(";
    }

    echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret , 'msg' => $msg));
}
```

View:

```
echo "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"ordemmobile\" value=\"".$registro->ordemmobile."\" style=\"width:80px; margin:0\" class=\"ordemmobile\"  data-id=\"".$registro->id."\" data-url=\"".base_url('adm/'.$this->router->fetch_class().'/ordemmobile')."\" /><span style=\"display:none\">".$registro->ordemmobile."</span></td>";
```

Model (alterar):

```
function alterar($data){
    $this->db->where('id',$data['id']);
    return $this->db->update('ga845_categorias',$data);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for `Categorias_model::alterar()`

Comment: I have updated my question, included "Model (alterar)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it should work if the inputs are getting posted. Checking both inputs would be a good idea.

Consider this

```
function ordemmobile()
{
    $ordemmobile = $this->input->post('ordemmobile');
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    if(empty($id) || empty($ordemmobile))
    {
        $ret = "danger";
        $msg = "Erro ao alterar a ordem :(";
    }
    else
    {
        $data['ordemmobile'] = $ordemmobile;
        $data['id'] = $id;

        if($this->categorias_model->alterar($data))
        {
            $ret = "success";
            $msg = "Ordem alterada com sucesso!";
        }
        else
        {
            $ret = "danger";
            $msg = "Erro ao alterar a ordem :(";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret, 'msg' => $msg));
}
```

You should also take a good look at what your browser's Web Developer Tools tell you about the request to and response from the server.